# Using a calendar in Xcode 4.2 iPhone

Tags: xcode, xcode4, ios5, xcode4.2

I have been learning Xcode 4.2 for a bit now and still can't get my head round on how the create a calendar so i really hope you guys can help me sort out my errors and maybe tell me what the next step in the code is to get this working i really appreciate your time thanks.

This is the storyboard

[image: this is my tabbed application storyboard]

.h there are no errors here

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <EventKitUI/EventKitUI.h>

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <EKEventEditViewDelegate> {

}

-(IBAction) createEvent; 

@end
```

.m this is where the errors are

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import <EventKitUI/EventKitUI.h>

@implementation FirstViewController

-(IBAction) createEvent {
    //Get the event store object
    EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc] INIT];

    //Cretae the EditViewController 
    EKEventEditViewController* controller = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc] INIT];
    controller.eventStore = eventStore;

    controller.editViewDelegate = self;

    [self presentModalViewController:controler animated:YES];

    [controller release];
}

//delegate method for EKEventEditViewDelegate
-(void)eventEditViewController:(EKEventEditViewController *)controller
         didCompleteWithAction:(EKEventEditViewAction)action {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Errors:

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc] INIT];
```

> Receiver type 'EKEventEditViewController' for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'init'

```
EKEventEditViewController* controller = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc] INIT];
```

> Receiver type 'EKEventEditViewController' for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'init'

```
[controller release];
```

> 'release' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode 2

That's all the errors hope you guys can tall me whats wrong i really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It's `init`, not `INIT`.
2. You need to get rid of the `[controller release];` if you're using ARC.

So, change to this:

```
-(IBAction) createEvent {
    //Get the event store object
    EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

    //Cretae the EditViewController 
    EKEventEditViewController* controller = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc] init];
    controller.eventStore = eventStore;

    controller.editViewDelegate = self;

    [self presentModalViewController:controler animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc] init];  one error incompatible pointer types initialising 'EKEventStore *_strong' with an expression of type 'EKEventEditViewController *'

Comment: @Paulmasters - updated. I missed your original typo of not `alloc`+`init`-ing the right class.

Comment: @mattjigalloway - if i was to add a alert message at the end once you have created event whats the code and do you no where i would put it ::)

Comment: @Paulmasters take a look at the the documentation for `UIAlertView` - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html

Comment: @mattjigalloway - ermm yeah have just been looking at that site and on youtube but i have found one video which is pretty good but not to sure where i link it to because i really want it so when i press the done button it then pops up